# Get eigenvectors corresponding to the p largest eigenvalues in Julia

Tags: julia, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I looked at `eigvecs` and `eigen` but they both do not order the eigenvectors by the magnitude of eigenvalues. Is this something that we have to code ourself?

```
testM=diagm(0=>[1,3,2])
eigvals(testM)
eigvecs(testM)
U=eigen(testM)
U.vectors
U.values
```

Comment: `U.vectors[:,sortperm(U.values).>1]` This I think works when you want to select all but the eigenvector corresponding to the smallest eigenvalue. So my question is, is there a better way? I mean thats always the question with programming. Its pretty easy to find a crappy method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The old answer was use `eigfact`. However, from v1.0, this has been renamed to `eigen` and moved to the standard library package `LinearAlgebra`, so you'll need a `using LinearAlgebra` at the top of your code. Once you've done this, you can see the docs for `eigen` using `?eigen`. Note, I've also updated this answer to replace `flipdim` with `reverse` (another v1.0 change).

For symmetric input, you can optionally pass in a `UnitRange{Int}` to get the eigenvectors corresponding to the `k` smallest or largest eigenvalues:

```
ef = eigen(Symmetric(x), 1:k)   #k smallest eigenvalues/vectors
ef.values
ef.vectors
```

or

```
K = size(x, 1)
ef = eigen(Symmetric(x), K-k+1:K) #k largest eigenvalues/vectors
ef.values
ef.vectors
reverse(ef.values, dims=1)    #If you want ordered largest to smallest
reverse(ef.vectors, dims=2)   #If you want ordered largest to smallest
```

For non-symmetric input, you need to compute all eigenvalues/vectors and then take whatever slice you want. The output is still sorted, so:

```
K = size(x, 1)
ef = eigen(x)
ef.values[1:k]           #smallest k
ef.vectors[:, 1:k]       #smallest k
ef.values[K-k+1:K]       #largest k
ef.vectors[:, K-k+1:K]   #largest k
```

As before, use `reverse` if you want the largest `k` ordered largest to smallest.

Comment: Maybe you should mention that in Julia >= 0.7 `eigfact` has been moved to `LinearAlgebra` stdlib.

Comment: @crstnbr oops agreed definitely worth mentioning. I'll fix it when I'm not on my phone. Cheers.

Comment: I can't find `eigfact` in the documentation for Julia 1.0.0?

Comment: @ztyh Yes, as crstnbr has pointed out, in v0.7+, `eigfact` has been moved to the standard library package `LinearAlgebra`. So just preface your code with `using LinearAlgebra` and then `?eigfact` will bring up the docs. I've adjusted my answer to reflect this. (I'm still getting used to the new standard library package structure in v0.7+ myself)

Comment: @ztyh Oops, just realised that `eigfact` has also now been renamed to `eigen`. Adjusting answer now.

Answer (score 3):

Colin's answer is great. Let me just add that there is also the package [Arpack.jl](https://julialinearalgebra.github.io/Arpack.jl/stable/) which provides bindings to the [ARPACK](https://www.caam.rice.edu/software/ARPACK/) Fortran library. The exported method `eigs` also has an option `nev` to specify the number of requested eigenvalues/vectors.